Finding weights from a linear system
I have a dataset with n individuals and each individual is randomly assigned codes from m possible integer codes. The structure is such that if a person contains multiple codes then each code is represented as a new row.
My goal is to identify all of the codes for each individual. My approach is to consider this as a linear system represented by $Ac = p$ where A is a nxm matrix of weights, c is a mx1 vector of codes, and p is the product of matrix multiplication. So,
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1m} \\
\vdots & \cdots & \vdots \\
a_{n1} & \cdots & a_{nm}
\end{pmatrix}, \quad c = \begin{pmatrix}
c_1 \\
c_2 \\
\vdots \\
c_m
\end{pmatrix} ,
\quad p = \begin{pmatrix}
p_1 \\
p_2 \\
\vdots \\
p_n
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $p_j = a_{j1}c_1 + a_{j2}c_2 + \cdots + a_{jm}c_m$
where $a_{jk} = 0$ if person j does not have code k and $a_{jk} = 1$ if person j has code k. I know c, I can find p, but I want A, but I'm struggling to think of the appropriate method. Also note that $n >> m$. Is this an appropriate set-up to solve this problem? In my linear algebra experience we often attempt to find $c$, and are given $A$, but in my set-up I have chosen to find $A$.
